# Laravel Using Auth:user() in testing is failing

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have a test that I am trying to run on a scoped DB query that returns only results from the currently logged in user's team. I am having issues with the test failing because Auth::user() doesn't seem to work when testing with actingAs. Here is my test:

```
/** @test */
function a_team_has_ten_tickets()
{
    $this->assertCount(10, $this->team_testing->tickets);
}
```

And the scoped query is:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    return $builder->where('team_id', Auth::user()->current_team_id);
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working, or how to make this work?

*Original question here:* https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/using-authuser-in-testing-is-failing

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object` which is referencing the line `return $builder->where('team_id', Auth::user()->current_team_id);`